# How can I find the cheapest Spirit flight from my location to anywhere?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, tips-and-tricks, spirit-airlines

I recently became a member of Spirit Airlines' $9 Fare Club.  I would like to maximize the benefit by planning my vacations around cheap Spirit fares. Basically, what I am looking for is a way to find the cheapest flights available on Spirit from my home airport to anywhere (i.e. no specified destination). Is there a way to find this information?

To be clear, I want to find cheap flights that are available, regardless of the dates that they are available.

Comment: On a given day, or just in general?

Comment: @Gagravarr Just in general

Answer (score 1):

It's kludgy, but you could always use [ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/) to search for flights from your home airport to anywhere Spirit flies.  The [Spirit timetable](https://www.spirit.com/content/documents/en-us/timetable12NOV2015.pdf) should make it fairly easy to get a list of airport codes for this purpose.  You can also specify the airline you want under "Advanced Routing Codes";  in this case, you would enter `NK`, which is Spirit's carrier code.

For example, if your home airport is Boston, you could consult the timetable to find that there are Spirit flights from BOS to ATL, DFW, FLL, RSW, LAS, MYR, and PBI.  Searching for round-trips with departure `BOS` and destination `ATL, DFW, FLL, RSW, LAS, MYR, PBI`, with routing code `NK`, yields the following results:
[image]
This is the search for a fixed date of departure & return, but you could equally well search for flights within a day or two of a given date, or search a range of dates using their "calendar of lowest fares" functionality.

This would become more tedious if your home airport is one of their "focus cities", with dozens of destinations;  but it would still in principle be possible, and might be your best option if nobody comes up with a better one.

Comment: I'd also like to be able to include trips that have multiple stops.

Comment: @Daniel:  That's trickier.  If a better option doesn't come up, you could always create a list of all of Spirit's destination airports, save it in a text file, and then cut-and-paste whenever you want to run the search.  It would be tedious, but you'd only need to do it once.

Comment: Ok that works. I'm also interested specifically in the price for $9 Fare Club members, though, and I think this won't work for that. I'm not sure if $9 Fare Club prices are proportional to regular prices

Answer (score 0):

The **extremely** flexible [Azuon](http://Azuon.com) app can do it as well, *but has a subscription fee*.  It has a huge list of airlines; you'd have to UNcheck all of them except Spirit.  You can make the source and/or destination list a whole country or continent (or several of them).  You can make the travel dates any range at all.  The subscription fee is small.